Movie with moving castle
I saw this movie when I was young (I was born in '82). It was a live action movie (NOT Howl's Moving Castle), in English, and I'm from the U.S. I reckon it can't have been made after 1992 or so.
If I remember correctly, it was a medieval/wizardy movie, kind of like Willow in its feel. 
There was a group of people who had to seek something in a castle that disappeared and reappeared in a new location each day.
There's a scene where an old blind man in the group is secretly killed and replaced by someone who looks exactly like him, but when nobody is looking his eyes roll back and he can see. It's super creepy.
And the other scene I remember is when they're in the castle and they're trapped between walls with spikes that are growing out of them and one guy gets very slowly impaled in the stomach on a growing spike. 

It seems that you're after Krull, although I'm not sure about the "old blind man" replacement, it's been years since I watched it. However all other details match.

Could this be Krull (1983)?

A prince and a fellowship of companions set out to rescue his bride
from a fortress of alien invaders who have arrived on their home
planet, Krull.

The scene with the spikes is here;



